# MarshalJSON not called

Tags: json, go, marshalling

I'm trying to customize the output of `MarshalJSON`, using the interface:

```
func (m *RawMessage) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
```

I followed that tutorial: http://choly.ca/post/go-json-marshalling/

My purpose is removing replace one of the fields with true/false (if set or not), so I ended up writing that function:

```
func (u *Edition) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    var vaultValue bool
    vaultValue = true
    var onlineValue bool
    vaultValue = false
    fmt.Println("here")
    if u.Vault == nil {
        vaultValue = false
    }
    if u.Online == nil {
        onlineValue = false
    }
    type AliasEdition Edition
    return json.Marshal(&struct {
        Vault  bool `json:"vault,omitempty"`
        Online bool `json:"online,omitempty"`
        *AliasEdition
    }{
        Vault:        vaultValue,
        Online:       onlineValue,
        AliasEdition: (*Alias)(u),
    })
}
```

The JSON is created from a map with the following instruction:

```
json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(EditionsMap)
```

Obviously `EditionsMap` is a Map of `Edition`s structures:

```
var EditionsMap map[string]datamodel.Edition
```

The problem is that the `MarshalJSON` function apparently is never called.

Probably I'm doing something wrong, but I cannot understand what is the problem, my understanding is that I just need to implement that function in order to get it called.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is because you declared the `Edition.MarshalJSON()` method with *pointer* receiver:

```
func (u *Edition) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
```

And you try to marshal non-pointer values (your map contains `datamodel.Edition` values):

```
var EditionsMap map[string]datamodel.Edition
// ...
json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(EditionsMap)
```

Methods with pointer receiver are not part of the method set of the corresponding non-pointer type. The method set of type `datamodel.Edition` **does not contain** the method `MarshalJSON()`.

[Spec: Method sets:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets)

> A type may have a *method* set associated with it. The method set of an [interface type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types) is its interface. **The method set of any other type `T` consists of all [methods](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations) declared with receiver type `T`.** The method set of the corresponding [pointer type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Pointer_types) `*T` is the set of all methods declared with receiver `*T` or `T` (that is, it also contains the method set of `T`).

Try to marshal pointer values, define your map to contain pointers:

```
var EditionsMap map[string]*datamodel.Edition
// ...
if err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(EditionsMap); err != nil {
    panic(err) // HANDLE error somehow, do not omit it like in your example!
}
```

Values of the pointer type `*Edition` **does have** a method `MarshalJSON()` which will be called properly by the `json` package. Try a working example of this on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/4LVWyCJ0Zb).

Another option would be to define the `Edition.MarshalJSON()` method with value receiver:

```
func (u Edition) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
```

And this way it would work no matter if you marshal pointer or non-pointer values, as the methods with value receiver are part of the method set of both the `Edition` type and the corresponding `*Edition` pointer type. Try a working example of this variant on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/2y71tmceTQ).

Comment: Isn't `EditionsMap` of the type `map[string]datamodel.Edition`?

Comment: hi icza, thank you for your answey, apparently i tried to change the map to contain pointers, but apparently with no luck, i also tried to change to declare the function without pointer, apparently with no luck! Ah and another question, can i change the type of an element during marshalJSON? The original Structure has for Vault and Online a type  of *struct{} (they are taken from an xml and they are empty nodes like: <vault />)

Comment: @Ivan See edited answer. I wrote a short, working example for both cases, you can view them on the Go playground (links in the answer). And yes, in your `MarshalJSON()` method you can change whatever you want to, it's really up to you what you return (how you marshal the value). You have complete freedom.

Comment: @icza thank you for you help, but i'm still having problem wiht my code. Here you can find the source file with MarshalJSON and all structures i'm using: https://github.com/inuyasha82/mtgrestservice/blob/marshaljson/datamodel/xmlmodel.go, i tried to make an example here https://play.golang.org/p/Z6JlpH0qjN and apparently it works, so something should be wrong in my original code, but cannot figure out what :'( The MarshalJson is never called.

Comment: @Ivan Are you sure code execution reaches that point? Insert log messages. Also [`Encoder.Encode()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Encoder.Encode) returns an `error`, please make sure you check that (currently you don't, see my edited answer how to do that).

Comment: @icza OMG, i found the issue, it was in the imports i didn't notice,but the import was updating an old version of that file in another package that i didn't delete, so any change that i made to it was not recognized by the application. Thank you for your help, you helped me understanding better the MarshalJSON feature! :)

Comment: This is a great answer.  I can't imagine why golang does it this way- it seems error prone.  I had the same problem as the OP.

Comment: @dcrobbins If you have a value (non-pointer), you would expect its methods not modify it (as it is "just" a value, not a pointer and passing it around creates copies). If pointer methods would be in its method set, they could modify it, which could be more confusing (than not including methods with pointer receivers in its method set).